# How to apply a function to object OR array of similar objects

Tags: javascript

`input` below can be either a singular Object, or an Array of same type of Objects. I want to apply `myFunction` to all those Objects in any case.

I do it like this with Lodash:

```
if (input.length !== undefined) {
    // Array
    return _.map(input, myFunction.bind(this, options));
}
else {
    // One object
    return myFunction(options, input);
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Use `Array.isArray` instead of testing for the `length` property.

Comment: Also, better bind `myFunction` to `null` instead of `this`

Comment: This sounds much like a question for [codereview.SE]

Comment: It's doable in vanilla JS if that's what you mean. You can also shorten the control statements, but overall no, checking the length is a good trick. You may consider using typeof as an alternative to be more explicit, but that's just spitting hairs.

Comment: So there's no built-in thing in Lodash that could replace the whole if/else statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting approach for you is using [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), so you would always receive an array in your function, simplifying it:

```
function f1(...input) {
  return _.map(input, myFunction.bind(this, options)); 
}

...

f1(o1); // call passing a single object 
f1(o1, o2); // call passing two objects 
f1(...[o1, o2]); // call passing an array with two objects
```

Comment: Very clever solution!

Comment: ...and I guess defined as `f1(func, ...args)`, the `myFunction` could be passed as a first argument e.g. `f1(myFunction, o1, o2)`.